# Неправильная работа алгоритма Флойда–Уоршелла

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы

Есть связный неориентированый граф, заданый матрицей смежности, который обрабатывается алгоритмом Флойда-Уоршелла. Учитывая то, что ребер между вершинами может не быть (тогда они заданы как `-1`), получается такой алгоритм:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      for(l=0;l<n;l++)
         if ((d[i][l]>d[i][j]+d[j][l]||d[i][l]<0)&&d[i][j]>=0&&d[j][l]>=0)
            d[i][l]=d[i][j]+d[j][l];
```

Вроде бы всё правильно, но почему-то не обрабатываются несколько ребер.

Например, обрабатывая графы, заданые такой матрицей:

```
 0 -1  1 2 
-1  0 -1 5 
 1 -1  0 4 
 2  5  4 0
```

В результате получается:

```
0 7 1 2 
7 0 9 5 
1 8 0 3 
2 5 3 0
```

Тоесть неизвестно как появляется длина ребра `9`.

В чём проблема? Где ошибка в написании алгоритма?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внешний цикл должен быть по **l**, внутренние по **i** и **j**.

Comment: Обьясните, пожалуйста, почему?

Comment: по тому что по i и j это пары вершин (от и до которой смотрим путь), а l это вершина которую мы добавляем при новом проходе и она должна добавляться только после того как алгоритм проверил все пути с предыдудещей вершиной (ну это если Вы понимаете алгоритм, а я думаю, что понимаете)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

До этого вопроса я считал, что порядок не имеет значение и меняет лишь "направление работы" алгоритма (с конца к началу, например), но, оказалось, что это совсем не так.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно в случае когда между вершинами нет ребра, указывают некоторую "бесконечность" INF, и тогда код приобретает следующий вид:

```
for (int k=0; k<n; ++k)
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        for (int j=0; j<n; ++j)
            if (d[i][k] < INF && d[k][j] < INF)
                d[i][j] = min (d[i][j], d[i][k] + d[k][j]);
```

UPD: Касательно ошибки вообще, у вас будет странно происходить релаксация, у Флойда-Уоршелла, для всех пар вершин, производиться попытка облегчить переход используя третью вершину, а в Ваших циклах, все совершенно иначе, итог - это нельзя назвать Флойд-Уоршелл

Comment: по-идее, указывать бесконечность в данном случае — то же самое, что и указывать `-1`, только вместо проверки, меньше ли ребро за бесконечность, проверяется, положительное ли оно.

Так же, нежелательно использовать функцию `min`, т.к. для её исполнения используется больше время.

Возможни ли сделать этот алгоритм с теми же условиями, что я описал? Просто не хочется просто переписывать кусок кода, интересно узнать, в чём проблема именно моего варианта `:)`

Comment: Указывать бесконечность или -1 - не одно и тоже.

Comment: Касательно ошибки вообще, у вас будет странно происходить релаксация, у Флойда-Уоршелла, для всех пар вершин, производиться попытка облегчить переход используя третюю вершину, а в ваших циклах, все совершенно иначе, итог - это нельзя назвать Флойд-Уоршелл

Comment: В этом случае разницы нет. 


Если указывать бесконечность — мы будем проверять, не уходят ли длины ребер за границу — тоесть не больше ли они бесконечности. Если оставлять `-1`, то мы проверяем принадлежность границе другим способом — граница в этом случае — отрицательные числа. Если слегка видоизменить и сравнить условия в этих двух способах — явно видна их схожесть. Разве не так?

Comment: //условие при использовании -1 как отсутствие ребра
    if (d[i][j]>=0 && d[j][l]>=0)
       if (d[i][l]>d[i][j]+d[j][l]||d[i][l]<0)
          d[i][l]=d[i][j]+d[j][l];
          
    //условие при использовании бесконечности как отсутствие ребра
    if (d[i][k] < INF && d[k][j] < INF)
       d[i][j] = min (d[i][j], d[i][k] + d[k][j]);

Отличие лишь в границах (как я и писал) и в слегка инном использовании функции `min`

Comment: Повторюсь про -1: никто не гарантирует, что не будет ребер с весом "-1" или "-10", к примеру. И про основную ошибку я уже написал выше: 
релаксация производиться не корректно.

Comment: За условием задачи вес ребра либо положительное число, либо `-1`, если ребра нет.

----

Насчет релаксации - я догадался, но в чем конкретно проблема? `:)`

Comment: добавил в ответ